# Visual Studio project with references on another system

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vsto

My employer had me program a specific program in VB. Net.
I finished it, and it works perfectly on my system. The problem is the following: He wants to be able to edit said program code on his PC, transferring it was simple.. Now (on his pc) the code is full of error signs because the references (Microsoft Word & Excel Project Libraries) can't be selected. It simply doesn't let him select the references because "a reference is already there, you have to delete "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" before adding the new reference" (loosely translated from German). I suspect the problem might be because I use Office 2016 while he used the 2010 version. Even so, how can I pull this off? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You could just provide a project with all Office related references removed - this would allow to add the correct ones on the target machine. You could also try to figure out the exact reference version information and prepare the project file using a text editor changing the reference entry.

Comment: @Filburt I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I just compared one of my own projects I upgraded from Word 2010 to Word 2013 - if you want to take the route of preparing your project I can post you the changes you need.

Comment: @Filburt Your idea with removing all references made it executable on the target system, but the office related steps still make the program crash. Would be really great if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To downgrade your project file, you need to replace a few elements referencing the respective Office libraries.

Basically you need to watch out for any occurrence of the Office version number `16.0` (Office 2016 in your case) and replace it with `14.0` (Office 2010).
My example shows `15.0` (Office 2013) but essentially it should be the same in the end for Office 2010.

I'll try to list each element and its replacement so you should be able to identify them in your .vbproj file:

**Word 2013 Interop**

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</Reference>
```

**Word 2010 Interop**

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</Reference>
```

**Word 2013 Project Extension**

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <FlavorProperties GUID="{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}">
      <ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="{29A7B9D7-A7F1-4328-8EF0-6B2D1A56B2C1}" OfficeVersion="15.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/w" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
      <Host Name="Word" GeneratedCodeNamespace="my_namespace_here" PublishedHash="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2FBF2B7EA72250886FF164DE6" IconIndex="0">
        <HostItem Name="ThisAddIn" Code="ThisAddIn.cs" CanonicalName="AddIn" PublishedHash="595051696E85B8CAE7EDD3B5EDE7B729864BC855" CanActivate="false" IconIndex="1" Blueprint="ThisAddIn.Designer.xml" GeneratedCode="ThisAddIn.Designer.cs" />
      </Host>
    </FlavorProperties>
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

**Word 2010 Project Extension**

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <FlavorProperties GUID="{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}">
      <ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="{29A7B9D7-A7F1-4328-8EF0-6B2D1A56B2C1}" OfficeVersion="" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/w" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
      <Host Name="Word" GeneratedCodeNamespace="my_namespace_here" PublishedHash="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2FBF2B7EA72250886FF164DE6" IconIndex="0">
        <HostItem Name="ThisAddIn" Code="ThisAddIn.cs" CanonicalName="AddIn" PublishedHash="595051696E85B8CAE7EDD3B5EDE7B729864BC855" CanActivate="false" IconIndex="1" Blueprint="ThisAddIn.Designer.xml" GeneratedCode="ThisAddIn.Designer.cs" />
      </Host>
    </FlavorProperties>
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll be sure to check it out as soon as I can.